# Why is Lord Hanuman Ji shown as carrying a flag in front of Goddess Durga?

Tags: hanuman, goddess, durga, kali

There is a popular story (shown in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ivDSTT7xf9I) video), according to which Lord Hanuman gained the favor of Goddess Kali by coming for her rescue. Lord Hanuman Ji also became known popularly as LANGAR VEER after that. This story is very popular in Maa Vaishno Devi Temple. Can anyone please provide the reference to the Hindu scripture which talks about this incident ?

Comment: Not a forum for the authenticity of videos found on the internet. It would be best to ask the author of the video their source.

Comment: Even Durga Chalisa (https://greenmesg.org/stotras/durga/durga_chalisa.php) refers to it: Kehari Vaahana Soha Bhavaanii |
Laangur Viira Calata Agavaanii ||


(I Salute You, O Mother Durga) You Reposing Gracefully upon the Lion as Mother Bhavani,
is welcome by the Brave Hanuman Moving Forward.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Thank you so much for your very kind and enlightening response

Comment: @Rickross Thank you, this was really helpful